# Insert Element in list during iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to insert element during iteration of list and did in following way. But I feel it can be written in better. Here B's dictionary which contain A element Length

```
_leftcell = leftcell[:]
index = 1
for A in leftcell:
    if B[A].length  % 140 != 0:
        _leftcell.insert(index, 2)
        index +=2
leftcell= _leftcell[:]
```

Comment: You are not iterating over `leftcell` here.

Comment: Sorry it's typo error and corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iterate over the list in reverse so you don't have to worry about changes at the end of the list

```
left_len = len(leftcell)
for i in xrange(left_len-1,0,-1):
    if B[leftcell[i]].length  % 140 != 0:
        leftcell.insert(i, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

```
for item in leftcell[:]:
    if B[item].length % 140:
        leftcell.insert(leftcell.index(item), 2)
```

Assuming I've correctly understood what you're trying to achieve.